# Is there an environment with GREP outside of InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

The GREP find and search integrated in InDesign is very powerful. Is there a similar smart way **outside of InDesign?**

Comment: I'm interested to know what "[research effort](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" went into framing this [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Comment: @Dɑvïd I've searched the web concerning this issue, but didn't found an explicit great answer. — I searched for a answer with a deeper background and short explanations. So everyone who's searching for this issue get a compiled answer here. I assume I have to document my researches.

Comment: Well, that's a bit baffling. Loads of [these results](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=grep) (not a tricky search!) would have satisfied the curiosity epxressed in the question. Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called regular expressions (regexp).

Most good editors have regexp support. Pesonally i use Scite, but most good text editors have this support these include but are not limited to notepad++, vim, sublime text.

Most *nix commandlines come equipped with a utilities for this. Such as **grep** or (**egrep** on most systems for regexp search), **sed** and **awk** that do the same thing if you have a mac or linux then most of these just work.

Most porgramming languages have direct regexp support, and those that do not have some module to implement it instead.

Many word processors include this feature, including [MS Word](https://superuser.com/questions/846646/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-a-pattern-in-a-ms-word-document), and many many others. In fact InDesign was probably one of the last programs to be added this feature.

Comment: While Word does have ‘wildcards’, I think it’s a bit of an exaggeration to say that it includes regex. The botched-up, half-baked and -assed tomfoolery included in Word probably does satisfy technical requirements to be considered a form of regular expression, but it’s about as regular and as close to what regular expressions set out to be as a banana is. (Can you tell I don’t like ‘wildcards’?)

Comment: features @JanusBahsJacquet I dont use word... But my understanding is that while the vocabulary is a bit weird and has no lookaheads its still relatively complete with back sunstitutions and all. Thena again there is no universal rule for how regexps should work as such there is quite many  dialects. Even adobes implementation is a bit botched especially the extensions adobe has added have a lot of bugs.